# When to use repeatable custom content

Tags: package, umbraco

I'm using umbraco 4.7.1 and the Repetable Custom Content Pacakge. My questions are:

I see questions that are saying that this package is not compatible with umbraco 4.7.1, but it is working fine for me... is the package compatible with umbraco 4.7.1 ?

When should I choose repetable custom content over creating nodes of a certain datatype ? Which option is better for performance ?

Is it possible to index/include repetable fields in examine search ?

Thanks.

[Repetable Custom Content](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/repeatable-custom-content)

Answer (score 0):

Repeatable custom content is very useful if the number of fields you have is small and they are logically part of the content node you are editing. By this I mean a collection of content that is part of the page you are editing. An example of which may be a list of links with a description, name etc.

Child nodes make most sense if the content is related but not necessarily part of the same page. Or if the content in question has lots of data. The trade off with child nodes is that they are slightly slower to add.

Another benefit of child nodes is that they are selectable and sharable amongst nodes easily. For instance a content panel that can be shared amongst pages.

There is no right or wrong way to use either nodes or repeatable content, however the main thing to consider is the ease of editing experience. As from a developer perspective it doesn't make much difference.

In terms of compatibility if you know that the package is working in a version of Umbraco that is not listed as compatible on the Package page on our.umbraco.org, then you can click the Report Compatibility link to indicate which version of Umbraco you have tested it with. This will ensure that the information is up to date.